# Newbie: Keybindings error in Elisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am trying to make a simple keybinding to the "na" function. When I execute (na) it inserts "å" in the current buffer, which it is supposed to, but the when I try the keybinding as described in the first line I get the error: "Wrong argument: commandp, na".
I am not sure if it matters, but I have also put the (local-set-key) command at the end of the code, but it produces the same error.

Now, I'm sure there is an easy solution to this. I just cannot see it =/

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-t") 'na)

(defun na ()
       "Liten å"
       (setq varlol "å")
       (insert varlol))
```

Comment: This is not your question exactly, but FYI "C-x 8 / a" does the same thing as the function you defined. "C-x 8 C-h" will list the various defined shortcuts for inserting latin-1 characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're missing is a call to [`interactive`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html#Using-Interactive):

```
(defun na ()
  "Liten å"
  (interactive)
  (setq varlol "å")
  (insert varlol))
```

From the documentation for it:

> This special form declares that a
>   function is a command, and that it may
>   therefore be called interactively (via
>   <kbd>M-x</kbd> or by entering a key
>   sequence bound to it). The argument
>   arg-descriptor declares how to compute
>   the arguments to the command when the
>   command is called interactively.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I was reading the Elisp Introduction Article on GNU and the (interactive) symbol had "p" included so I automatically put that into the parantheses but got an error. I should have thought that the "p" means that it expects to recieve data. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @DreamCodeR Check out the docs for `interactive` to see the various arguments.  The `"p"` indicates the prefix argument (`C-u`) is converted to a number.  But, the error you got was that the function `na` *doesn't* have any arguments, so the error was most likely that you specified (via `interactive`) the function should have one argument, but the actual definition had none.

Answer (score 2):

"interactive" is missing

```
(defun na ()
  (interactive)
       "Liten å"
       (setq varlol "å")
       (insert varlol))
```